# fadein fadeout repeatedly on multi-text in single widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new user in flutter mobile app. How to make fade in fade out repeatedly for  multi text with in same or single widget. As like following link, https://www.radio5ive.com/.
I have used `AnimatedOpacity` widget, but it's not properly working.

```dart
// text show hide
  double opacity = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    changeOpacity();
  }

  changeOpacity() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity = opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        changeOpacity();
      });
    });
  }
```

And I am using it like

```dart
   Container(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: opacity,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Television contracts the imagination and radio expands it.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),



//full code below
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // const ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  Duration duration = new Duration();
  Duration position = new Duration();
  bool playing = false;

  // disposing listener if not needed or users navigates away from
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    audioPlayer.dispose();
  }

  // text show hide
  double opacity = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    changeOpacity();
  }

  changeOpacity() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        opacity = opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        changeOpacity();
      });
    });
  }
  // changeOpacity() {
  //   Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (t) {
  //     setState(() {
  //       opacity = opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
  //       changeOpacity();
  //     });
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // color: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff252525),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffffcb05),
          // title: Text('Radio5ive'),
          title: Image.asset(
            'assets/logoradio.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 40,
            width: 40,
          ),

          actions: [IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {})],
          // flexibleSpace: Icon(Icons.camera),
          // flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
          //   child: Image(
          //     image: AssetImage('assets/logoradio.png'),
          //     height: 30,
          //     width: 30,
          //   ),
          // ),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          elevation: 10.0,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text('sundar'),
                accountEmail: Text('sundar@gmail.com'),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  child: Text('xyz'),
                ),
                otherAccountsPictures: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    child: Text('ABC'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('HOME'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.mail),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 0.5,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('PODCAST'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.mail),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 0.5,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('ABOUT'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.mail),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 0.5,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('CONATACT'),
                leading: Icon(Icons.people),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: opacity,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Television contracts the imagination and radio expands it.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: opacity == 1 ? 0 : 1,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      'Television contracts the imagination and radio expands it.',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Container(
              //   child: Image(
              //     image: AssetImage('assets/logoradio.png'),
              //     height: 100,
              //     width: 100,
              //   ),
              // ),
              // slider(),
              Container(
                  child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  getAudio();
                },
                child: Icon(
                  playing == false
                      ? Icons.play_circle_outline
                      : Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                  size: 50,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Slider.adaptive(
        min: 0.0,
        value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            audioPlayer.seek(new Duration(seconds: value.toInt()));
          });
        });
  }

  void getAudio() async {
    var url = "https://live.radio5ive.com/proxy/radio5ivetamil/stream";
    // var url = "https://radio5ive.com/public/Neeye-Oli-MassTamilan.fm.mp3";
    // var url =
    //     "https://ia800905.us.archive.org/19/items/FREE_background_music_dhalius/backsound.mp3";
    // playing is false by default
    if (playing) {
      //pause song

      var res = await audioPlayer.pause();
      print('test');
      print(url);
      if (res == 1) {
        setState(() {
          playing = false;
        });
      }
    } else {
      //play song
      var res = await audioPlayer.play(url, isLocal: true);
      if (res == 1) {
        setState(() {
          playing = true;
        });
      }
    }
    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      setState(() {
        duration = dd;
      });
    });
    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((Duration dd) {
      setState(() {
        position = dd;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using  `Future.delayed` means it will run for single time, you need to use  `Timer.periodic` in this case

```dart
changeOpacity() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (t) {
      setState(() {
        opacity = opacity == 0.0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
      });
    });
  }
```

On after delay it's taking 2 second to animate and while the timer is periodic and don't wait for animation to end, it is overlapping.

---

**Update 2** multipleTextFade translation

Simply use [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)

```dart
SizedBox(
        width: 250.0,
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 32.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          child: AnimatedTextKit(
            animatedTexts: [
              FadeAnimatedText('do IT!'),
              FadeAnimatedText('do it RIGHT!!'),
              FadeAnimatedText('do it RIGHT NOW!!!'),
            ],
            onTap: () {
              print("Tap Event");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

---

**Update** for single animation

To get the perfect animation, use `FadeTransition`

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat(reverse: true);

  late final Animation<double> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FadeTransition(
            opacity: _animation,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(
                'Television contracts the imagination and radio expands it.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FadeTransition(
            key: ValueKey("animated 2"),
            opacity: _animation,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(
                'Television contracts the imagination and radio expands it.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about

- [Timer class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Timer-class.html)
- [FadeTransition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeTransition-class.html)
- [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)

Comment: i have used this following  code but its not working  in my case. the text fadein fadeout in signle widget but using this code it stucks in same place there is no fadein fadeout. if possible provide working demo.

Comment: are you using `stack` widget as  it's parent?

Comment: there was an typo error, fixed it, check update, if it fails, can you include full widget ?

Comment: no bro  only used AnimatedOpacity

Comment: Can you include more details on your use cases, in my case it is working fine, try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app.

Comment: i have attached the full code  can u pls cehck once

Comment: can you try again with providing key on `AnimatedOpacity` and then  `flutter clean` and rebuild with my updated answer.

Comment: Use `FadeTransition`

Comment: bro now working fine but the entire text(text1 and text2 ) is fading out and in, at the same time. ineed the text to fadein fadeout one by one. i have sent sample link for  your reference. fadein fadeout shoud resemble as in the link. https://www.radio5ive.com/

Comment: Same time because we are using same controller, Also for your need i think [animated_text_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) is just perfect

Comment: Very thank u somuch bro animated text kit working fine .......

Comment: should I include that process here?